# how to use nested dictionary in python which return user defined variable

Tags: python

I am trying to fetch value of `time` if found in people it should print time otherwise without time

Below is code which I am trying to test:

```
import datetime
people = {1: {'time': '', 'age': '27', 'sex': 'Male'},
          2: {'time': '', 'age': '22', 'sex': 'Female'}}

time = datetime.datetime.now()
for time in people.items():
    if time in people.items():
        print(people,"true");
    else:
        print(people,"false");
```

The output is :

```
{1: {'age': '27', 'sex': 'Male', 'time': ''}, 2: {'age': '22', 'sex': 'Female', 'time': ''}} true
{1: {'age': '27', 'sex': 'Male', 'time': ''}, 2: {'age': '22', 'sex': 'Female', 'time': ''}} true
```

I want it to display the value of current timestamp value in `time`.

Desired output:

```
{1: {'age': '27', 'sex': 'Male', 'time': '2021-06-17T05:42:32.204965'}, 2: {'age': '22', 'sex': 'Female', 'time': '2021-06-17T05:42:32.204965'}} true
```

Refrence:

```
{
  "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:Device:filling001",
  "type": "FillingSensor",
  "filling": {
    "type": "Property",
    "value": 0.94,
    "unitCode": "C62",
    **"time": "2021-01-28T12:33:10.000Z"**
  },
  "time_index": "2021-01-28T12:33:20.476"
}
```

What i am doing wrong here. help on this will be great?

Comment: You are iterating over `time in people.items()` so `if time in people.items()` will always be true. Can you add your desired output?

Comment: Why do you expect `time` to not be in `people.items()` if you get it by iterating `people.items()` ?

Comment: added desire output @JohnnyMopp

Comment: You say "found in people it should print time otherwise without time" but then say "I want it to display the value of current timestamp value in time."  Which is it? Are you just looking to set the time attribute in your dictionary?

Comment: yes...i want it to print value of timestamp in time attribute if found otherwise not @JonSG

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code :

1. You use the same variable `time` with `time = datetime.datetime.now()` and `for time in people.items()` so the second will overwrite the first one value.
2. `people.items()` returns a tuple of key, value elements, ie: `(1, {...})` so you cannot compare `time` with (key, value).
3. Using `in` operator for this seems quite wrong to me, I would try something like below.

.

```
time = datetime.datetime.now()
for key, val in people.items():
  print({key:val}, "true" if val.get("time") == time else "false")
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to initialize `time` as `datetime.datetime.now()` before the dictionary initialization, and then replace the empty quotes with `time`.

Comment: time will be user defined if user define time then it should print its value otherwise no value of time